# HarpJS - Show only the first, latest blog post

Tags: pug

I have the following in jade (as an example):

```
for post, slug in public.posts._data

  article
      h1= post.title

      != partial("posts/" + slug)
```

I'm trying to display JUST the first newest post (with Jekyll this is simply done as 'limit: 1')

I can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: As the author suggested _data was not an array but an object. `public.posts._contents` provided an ordered list so here is the solution:

```
- var post = public.posts._data[public.posts._contents[0].toString().replace('.html', '')]

  article
      h1= post.title
  ...
```

Comment: I thought that would work as well, but it then fails to understand what `h1= post.title` is. Sees it as undefined.

Comment: You should track what data goes into the render call. e.g. log public.posts out and see of _data[0] has a post object. I've tested this on Jade and it seems to work as long as posts._data is an array filled with objects.

Comment: Thank you for the codepen :)

It seems the title does exist when printing the json:

`"posts": {
  "_contents": [
   "sony-vr.html",
   "test.html"
  ],
  "_data": {
   "sony-vr": {
    "title": "For Playstation VR to succeed, it just needs one thing"
   },
   "test": {
    "title": "Testing, you shouldn't see this!"
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: seems like the _data variable is an object. Do you happen to have a created date or updated date for posts?

Comment: Yes I use created dates (just didn't have them in there for the testing)

Comment: You can sort the items based on date and select the most recent post. Although it is not an ideal solution. A module like lodash can help you do this easily _.sortBy(posts, 'createdAt')[0] but overall that would not be ideal in production. Any chance you could take a look at public and see if it has a property post?

Comment: `{
 "_contents": [
  "404.html",
  "index.html"
 ],
 "_data": {
  "about": {
   "title": "My default title",
   "description": "My default description"
  }
 },
 "css": {
  "_contents": [
   "main.css"
  ]
 },
 "posts": {
  "_contents": [
   "sony-vr.html",
   "test.html"
  ],
  "_data": {
   "sony-vr": {
    "title": "For Playstation VR to succeed, it just needs one thing"
   },
   "test": {
    "title": "Testing, you shouldn't see this!"
   }
  }
 }
}`

Comment: Is _contents sorted based on date? In that case you can do something like posts._data[posts._contents[0]]

Comment: No I was incorrect, the _contents just reads the posts in the order they are added in the posts/_data.json (Thank you for all the help so far, really appreciated)

Comment: I find the following 'works' but it only returns the 'sony-vr' not the 'title' inside

`- var post = public.posts._data

    article
        h1= Object.keys(post)[0]`

Comment: I suggest assigning post variable to the first element of the object. Just to clarify, as I've taken a look at the contents again it seems like your _data has more than one element inside. Now since Objects are not indexed you may get a top post but not the most recent one as the result. Is that correct? In that case - var post = public.posts._data[public.posts._contents[0]] is your best bet

Comment: I've updated the answer (easier to read the code there) let me know if the solution works for you.

Comment: Still undefined post.title (I might just stick with Jekyll since it seems to handle things like this easily lol)

Comment: Sorry I referenced it wrong. It should be working. I'll update the answer in a minute.

Comment: Turns out the _contents end with .html. I've patched it above.